# CSS comments in nested LESS rules

Tags: css, less

How can I add CSS comments in LESS nested rules? Ex:

```
div{
    span{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    /*This is my comment*/
    em{
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

This is the output I expect to get:

```
div span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
/*This is my comment*/
div em {
  color: blue;
}
```

But, unfortunatelly this is how it is processed:

```
div {
  /*This is my comment*/
}
div span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
div em {
  color: blue;
}
```

Is it possible to make this?

Comment: You don't want comments in the complied CSS...that's why you use a pre-processor. Oh. and it looks like you are making up your own elements (`em`)...please don't do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D - <em> means emphasized text.

Comment: @Paulie_D LOL. Here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_em.asp

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using `/* */`.

The reason being that it is still under the `div` scope, so it won't work using `/* */` comments.

However, in `LESS` you can use `//` for single line comments which doesn't go through the compiler (so doesn't end up in the compiled `CSS` code but will be in the `LESS` code).

[Here is the official documentation on comments](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-comments).

Comment: Yes I know. The idea is to get CSS comments in .css file not for less, but anyways looks like this is not possible. :(

Comment: Oh, my apologies thought you wanted it other way round! Sorry :( @Smartik

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get your comment *inside* nested rules:

```css
div {
    em { 
        /* This is my comment */
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

output:

```css
div em {
  /* This is my comment */
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed that, it's a bit unusual, but looks like right now this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be useful for you.

```
/*This is my comment*/
div {
   em {     
       color: blue;
   }
   span {
       font-size: 16px;
       color: #fff;
   }   
}
```

and the output will be,

```
/*This is my comment*/
div em {
  color: blue;
}
div span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

More or less it would be like what you are expecting !!!